# How to add different margin on different breakpoints in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to add 3 different margin-top, one on mobile screen, one on ipad and one on desktop view. So far I'have used the mt-3 but it gives the same margin in all the viewports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grid size for diffrent devices, in following example I used sm for mobile, md for ipad and lg for desktop

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="mt-sm-5 mt-md-4 mt-lg-3"></div>
```